# Вывод HTML через AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Господа, пилю чат и вывожу сообщения через Ангулар

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="msg in messages">
  <td class="span2" ng-bind="msg.name+':'"></td>
  <td class="span7" ng-bind="msg.text"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

И надо бы к msg.text применить регексп, но HTML-теги при этом экранируются. А я хочу интерпретировать.

```
msg.text = msg.text.replace(/[>][0-9]{5}/i, function myFunction(x){return '<strong>'+x+'</strong>';});
```

Изините, что прошу, но хотелось-бы решение без ng-bind-html, это важно.

Comment: почему без `ng-bind-html`? а также непонятно какая строка подается на выход и какой ожидается результат?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь к вопросу @Grundy. Почему нужно решение без `ng-bind-html`?

Конечно, мы можем не знать всей задачи. И, если это действительно нужно, то можете решить вашу задачу через **директиву**.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szjoe3j3/1/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    this.messages = [{
      name: "Stuart",
      text: "Hello <b>Bob</b>"
    }, {
      name: "Bob",
      text: "Hello <strong>Stuart</strong>"
    }, {
      name: "Kevin",
      text: "Hello <i>Kevin</i>"
    }];
  })
  .directive('myBindHtml', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        myBindHtml: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        scope.$watch('myBindHtml', function(newVal) {
          //Здесь можете делать любые преобразования текста перед выводом.
          elem.html(newVal);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as ex">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="msg in ex.messages">
          <td class="span2" ng-bind="msg.name+':'"></td>
          <td class="span7" my-bind-html="msg.text"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```